# Predict smearing of FFT

Tags: c++, signal-processing, fft

After applying a Fourier transform to a signal, the energy of a single sine wave is often spread out across multiple bins (aka smearing). Have a look at the right side of the image below for an illustration:

[image: An example of smearing]

I want to extract a list of peak frequencies. Just finding the highest bin is easy. But after that smearing becomes a problem.

I would like to have a heuristic which tells me if the magnitude of a specific bin is possibly the result of smearing or if there **has** to be another peak frequency in order to explain the signal. (It is better if I miss some than have false positives)

My naive approach would be to just calculate a few thousand examples and take the maximum of these to get an envelope curve so that any smearing is likely below that envelope.

But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is this for any specific programming language? If not, perhaps you'd have more luck asking this on [Math Overflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) instead.

Comment: Why not use a suitable window function prior to the FFT so that you don't have to worry about spectral leakage ? Your peaks will be more accurate as a result too.

Comment: @PaulR That would greatly reduce the magnitude of the problem, without actually solving it, because I would still need a heuristic for the new smearing behavior then.

Comment: @PaulR is correct, you need a better windowing function. The "smearing" as you call it is the actual frequency of the signal, it's not some artifact produced by the FFT.

Comment: @GoBusto I think http://dsp.stackexchange.com/ is a little more relevant than math

Answer (score 1):

The FFT result of any rectangularly windowed pure unmodulated sinusoid is a Sinc function.  This Sinc (sin(pi*x)/(pi*x)) function is only zero for all bins except one (at the peak magnitude) when the frequency of the input sinusoid has exactly an integer number of periods in the FFT width.

For all other frequencies that are not at the exact center of an FFT result bin, if you know that exact frequency and magnitude (which won't be in any single FFT bin), you can calculate all the other bins by sampling the Sinc function.

And, of course, if the input sinusoid isn't perfectly pure, but modulated in any way (amplitude, frequency or phase), this modulation will produce various sidebands in the FFT result as well.